# Login usability is awful, especially from email

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, usability

I received an email from Careers 2.0. So my email is known. I click the link to log in, but it requires me to enter my email. It could easily be entered for me from the link I clicked.

Type email address.

I check "remember me" but forgot my password. So at that point my email is stored.

Click "forgot password" and I'm asked to enter my email. Really?

Click "feedback is welcome". Apparently at meta, feedback is always a question? Hardly.

Go to enter my "question" and...

I'm asked to log in.

[head->desk]

The only thing Careers 2.0 got right was not wiping my email after I'd entered an incorrect password. Thanks for that.

Comment: It continues: I typed in my email in 'forgot password' and I get "We don’t see an existing account for that email. Let’s create one...".

Comment: Mark, check your email. I sent you your account details. Cheers

Comment: @MarkBeckleyRoberts do you recall what email triggered off this chain of events?

Answer (score 3):

I just pushed a build that fixes some of the pain points here, in particular:

- If you already filled in your email and tried to login then 'Forgot Password' will pre-populate your email.
- When you visit the invitation page from an invite email we'll populate the relevant fields.

If you have more information on the specific email you received then we can verify that the path from there is fixed too.

Unfortunately, there isn't much we can do about the 'Feedback is welcome' piece. Your experience there is related to the fact that Careers' and SE's login mechanisms are not the same. Merging those is on our longer term roadmap though.